# 'windbg' unable to load symbols when run as system account

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I am trying to analyse MEMORY.DMP using **windbg**/**cdb**/**kd** debugging tools with in a Powershell script that runs only with system account. 
I have provided symbol file path and "**!sym noisy**" prompt is on.

- Symbol file path:

```
"SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols"
```

I was able to download and load symbols in **windbg**/**cdb**/**kd** when ran as **Administrator**.

```
SYMSRV:  File: ntkrnlmp.exe

SYMSRV:  Get File Path: download/symbols/ntkrnlmp.exe/5C8C79C8708000/ntkrnlmp.exe


SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.

SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.
SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully received a  copied         
 copied         
DBGHELP: c:\symbols\ntkrnlmp.exe\5C8C79C8708000\ntkrnlmp.exe - OK
```

but I not able download and load symbols in windbg/cdb/kd when ran as "**NT Authority/System**" on the same machine.

```
*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that   ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: nt!_KPRCB                                     ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************

SYMSRV:  c:\symbols\ntkrnlmp.exe\5C8C79C8708000\ntkrnlmp.exe not found
SYMSRV:  c:\symbols\ntkrnlmp.exe\5C8C79C8708000\ntkrnlmp.exe not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntkrnlmp.exe/5C8C79C8708000/ntkrnlmp.exe not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntkrnlmp.exe/5C8C79C8708000/ntkrnlmp.exe not found
SYMSRV:  c:\symbols\ntoskrnl.exe\5C8C79C8708000\ntoskrnl.exe not found
SYMSRV:  c:\symbols\ntoskrnl.exe\5C8C79C8708000\ntoskrnl.exe not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntoskrnl.exe/5C8C79C8708000/ntoskrnl.exe not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/ntoskrnl.exe/5C8C79C8708000/ntoskrnl.exe not found
```

why debugging tools not loading symbols with system account? if it is not possible is there any other work around?

Comment: Just a guess, but when launched as the Local System account, WinDbg might be using the `dbghelp.dll` in the System32 folder. The `dbghelp.dll` in which ships with Windows in System32 cannot use http symbol servers.

Comment: yes , you are correct.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095328/cannot-download-microsoft-symbols-when-running-cdb-in-a-windows-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is provided here.

> **[Cannot download microsoft symbols when running cdb in a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095328/cannot-download-microsoft-symbols-when-running-cdb-in-a-windows-service)**