# ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when using dbghelp as a service

Tags: c++, windows, iis, winhttp, symbol-server

I am trying to setup a symbol proxy server that targets both our own internal symbol stores (UNC) and http servers (microsofts being one). I want it to run as a service, or as IIS (which runs as a service of course).

I have tried [Micrsoft SymProxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symproxy), and am now trying [pySymProxy](https://github.com/inbilla/pySymProxy).
pySymProxy works just fine when I run it from desktop, but has this WINHTTP error when run as a service (/via IIS).

I have tried every fix mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095328/cannot-download-microsoft-symbols-when-running-cdb-in-a-windows-service), including using the `DBGHELP_WININET`, and setting the registry settings. These have no effect at all. I believe this information is out of date now, but I can't find anywhere that suggests what the latest recommendation for this is. I also don't understand what the underlying problem is either. Every method I have tried so far tells me I am NOT behind a proxy. WinHttp says it is not *using* a proxy in the log entry, so why can it not simply resolve a name like it can when run from the desktop?

Example from my log when it fails, while running from a service:

```
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x4
         C:\SymProxy\cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         kernelbase.pdb
         0C3B0BCF250566567FA913502B5677C81
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\SymProxy\cache\kernelbase.pdb\0C3B0BCF250566567FA913502B5677C81\kernelbase.pdb - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\SymProxy\cache\kernelbase.pdb\0C3B0BCF250566567FA913502B5677C81\kernelbase.pd_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\SymProxy\cache\kernelbase.pdb\0C3B0BCF250566567FA913502B5677C81\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  WinHttp interface using proxy server: none
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/index2.txt
SYMSRV:  WinHttpSendRequest: 800C2EE7 - ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/kernelbase.pdb/0C3B0BCF250566567FA913502B5677C81/kernelbase.pdb
SYMSRV:  WinHttpSendRequest: 800C2EE7 - ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x800C2EE7
```

Example of it working totally fine when run from desktop:

```
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x4
         C:\SymProxy\cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         kernelbase.pdb
         0C3B0BCF250566567FA913502B5677C81
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\SymProxy\cache\kernelbase.pdb\0C3B0BCF250566567FA913502B5677C81\kernelbase.pdb - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\SymProxy\cache\kernelbase.pdb\0C3B0BCF250566567FA913502B5677C81\kernelbase.pd_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\SymProxy\cache\kernelbase.pdb\0C3B0BCF250566567FA913502B5677C81\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/index2.txt
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo(HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH): 800C2F76 - ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/kernelbase.pdb/0C3B0BCF250566567FA913502B5677C81/kernelbase.pdb
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 801900c8 - HTTP_STATUS_OK
SYMSRV:  kernelbase.pdb from http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 7687168 bytes -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (not particularly nice) work around for this issue is to use an OLD version of dbghelp.dll and symsrv.dll, which still supports the `DBGHELP_WININET` flag.

This is also confirmed by the original dbg author as an unsolvable problem [here](https://microsoft.public.windbg.narkive.com/xfnt9LTe/cdb-exe-unable-to-download-symbols-when-run-from-service#post8). As MS symbol servers are automatically redirecting to https, there is no way using WinHTTP for the SymProxy to work with them from what I understand.

I have confirmed this working with dbghelp version 6.11.1.404. I have confirmed it NOT working with dbghelp 10.0.15063.400 (or newer presumably). I don't know anything about the intervening versions.

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved. It is so appreciated if you can mark your solution as answer.